# Best practices for getting the most testing coverage with Django/Python?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

My tests are seriously lacking and I don't have a whole lot of faith in them. What are some of the best practices for getting the most testing coverage I can using Django/Python? I've been taking a look at [Freshen](https://github.com/rlisagor/freshen) and [Lettuce](http://lettuce.it), which look pretty promising, but I can't use them for *everything*, can I? I'm looking for advice on how to structure my workflow/project with testing so that I can feel confident when deploying new code in a production environment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Additionally this series of articles so far has some good advice on testing django apps:

http://toastdriven.com/blog/2011/apr/10/guide-to-testing-in-django/

My only criticism of the answer would be to not store everything in the `tests.py` file, but do as the article suggest. Create a `tests` directory and turn it in to a module by adding an `__init__.py` file and importing all your test cases there. eg `from myapp.tests.views import *`. But definitely sound advice. Gotta walk before you can run… `tests`! See what I did there?

Comment: Although my previously chosen best answer was a bit more thorough, I think the article you provided more clear-cut guidance and helped me understand testing better.

Comment: Here is another very detailed Test Driven Tutorial that covers LiveServerTestCase tests with selenium as well http://www.tdd-django-tutorial.com

Answer (score 38):

1. Stop coding.
2. Write the tests for the things your application is supposed to do.

First, use the built-in Django testing.  Write model tests as TestCase classes inside your models.py.

Do that now.  Before reading any further.  Add `django.test.TestCase` classes right now that create, modify and retrieve model objects.  Be sure you have a test method for each property, attribute, or extra method you defined.

I'll wait until you've finished that.

---

Model tests complete?  Good.

Now create a tests.py file in each application.  Every single one.  All empty.

In each tests.py file create `django.test.TestCase` classes for each Form.

Do it now.  Create good and bad forms.  Create forms with each individual field validation problem.

Don't create all possible permutations of bad data.  Just one test case for each individual validation rule.

Do that now.  Before reading any further.  Add `django.test.TestCase` classes to tests.py for each Form.

I'll wait until you've finished that.

---

Now, you have to test each view function.  They also go in the tests.py file.  Each view function has at least two test cases, perhaps more, depending on the various decorators you're using.

If a view function requires a login, you have two cases: logged in and not logged in.

If a view function requires a permission, you have at least three cases: not logged in, logged in as the wrong user, logged in as the right user.

For now, you just need to be sure that the view function did *something* and returns the correct HTML template with any piece of correct data.  Don't go crazy.  You just want to be sure all view functions actually return an expected page.  Nothing more.

Do that now.  Before reading any further.  Add `django.test.TestCase` classes to tests.py for each view function.

I'll wait until you've finished that.

---

Those are the tests you should write **first** before writing any application code.

This will give you a testing baseline that confirms that your application will minimall sort-of run.

One you have that finished, you can start to consider unit tests that reflect the real purpose and value behind your application.

Comment: I'm using this strategy, and the only pitfall I see with this approach is that (at least, I was) one can feel encouraged to put too much business logic in the models and/or forms (instead of waiting for the views layer to come up and integrate some of the logic in), thereby making the application needlessly complex.

Comment: @LaundroMat: "too much business logic in the models" can't happen.  A lot of business logic *belongs* in the models.  The problems arise when business logic is put in the templates and the form widgets.

Comment: @S. Lott - Aha, that is interesting. I always felt models should be useable across different applications, and thus not include too much application specific logic. With what you're saying, I guess I can put that feeling of unrest each time I introduce complex logic in the models away. Thanks :)

Comment: @LaundroMat: Models are not the unit of reuse in Django.  Applications -- as a whole -- are the unit of reuse.

Comment: @S.Lott When you say to write tests in the `models.py`, I couldn't find any sources saying that the tests should be anywhere but in a tests folder or `tests.py`. Would you say its better in the `models.py` instead of in a tests directory? I am referring to your first step/instruction.

Comment: Also, I have a model that doesn't define any custom methods, just some fields and a `__Meta__` class and `__unicode__` function. Should I test that model specifically for anything?

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming that you are done with [Testing Django Applications](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/). With the right set of helper tools you should be fine with the default unit testing using Django test framework.

To get you started with measuring coverage you might want to look into [coverage](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage) standalone to figure out what you have tested.

Once installed, you can do something like this:

```
$ coverage run manage.py test *yourapp*
```

It will create `.coverage` file for you. You can format the data from this file with

```
$ coverage report
```

to get a full list on testing coverage (including code from other python libraries).
You can easily `coverage report --omit path` modules that start with particular paths. Additionally you would be able to see the lines that were not executed during the test run with `-m` option.

Also, I think there is a `django_coverage` Django application that integrates `coverage` into testing for Django project. It makes nice HTML coverage reports for you.

Now there are other tools like twill, etc. to address specific needs (like javascript testing).

Also, if you want to go through the detailed baby steps of setting up vanilla testing under Django, you may want to read "Django 1.1 Testing and Debugging" (lookup on Amazon).